# Translation of a greek word in Stoic thought

Tags: ancient-philosophy, stoicism, translation

I'm reading [this](http://secure.pdcnet.org/ancientphil/content/ancientphil_1984_0004_0001_0083_0096) article on Ariston of Chios. On the 9th page of the article Schofield uses " ἡγεμονιχόν", stating that the "What Ariston had noticed was that, although committed to a plurality of virtues, the Stoics nonetheless were content to identify just one condition of the  ἡγεμονιχόν as constituting ενφνια, excellence of natural endowment."

What does this greek word translate to in English? I suspect that it is something like "commanding faculty of the soul", but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: The subtleties of Ancient Greek can be lost in the modern tongue, but according to my close Greek friend it transliterates to "hegemonichon," which sounds a lot like "hegemony."  Hegemony is basically authority or sovereignty, and the "monichon" sounds like "monos" or "monachos," "alone."  He reckons the word refers to the idea of being a sovereign individual, in control of one's own thoughts and actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Stoic theory, there are eight parts of the soul, the "commanding faculty","ἡγεμονιχόν", or mind, the five senses, voice and certain aspects of reproduction. The mind, which is located at the heart, is a center that controls the other soul-parts as well as the body, and that receives and processes information supplied by the subordinate parts.

Comment: So the correct translation would be something like "Mind"?

Comment: yes, the commanding faculty of the soul, the mind.

Comment: Ok, thanks much. Since the author uses "commanding faculty of the soul" elsewhere, I'll stick to that.